Tkinter wait_variable keeps waiting after the buttom is pressed in the second called of the class
I have a Tkinter window inside a class. This class is called from several protocols (Each one is a different script). In one of the protocols, the window works perfectly and gets the job done for all the iterations (it creates several Sample classes depending on how many Samples there is in a file) but for the rest of the protocols it gets stuck waiting for the variable in the second Sample (but works perfectly for the first sample). I have been driving myself crazy for some weeks trying to solve this issue. The buttom works perfectly, as it works in the first iteration and in the other protocol. Also, the button is getting pressed everytime I pressed it (It says BUTTON PRESSED everytime xd) but is still stuck in wait.
Sorry if my code is not the cleanest or my question is not well expressed. I am not a computer scientist nor a programmer, just a Biochemist trying my best to use programming!
class Sample:

    def __init__(
        self,
        sample_id: int,
        data: pd.DataFrame,
        output_path: pathlib.Path,
        file_name: str,
        window_size: int,
        concentration_generator: Type[ConcentrationGenerator],
        properties: List[str] = ["peptidoglycan"],
        n_reps: Optional[int] = None,
        n_concentrations: Optional[int] = None,
        repetition_has_control: bool = True,
        controls: Optional[List[Control]] = None,
    ) -> None:
        self.id = sample_id + 1
        self.repetition_has_control = repetition_has_control
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry("650x250")
        self.window.resizable(False, False)
        self.window.title(f"Sample {self.id}")
        self.window.config(background="#D8C7F0")

        ## LABELS
        sample_name_label = tk.Label(self.window, text="Sample name:", bg="#D8C7F0")
        sample_name_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

        # ENTRYS
        sample_name_entry = tk.Entry(
            self.window,
            bg="#D8C7F0",
            width=30,
        )
        sample_name_entry.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.properties = dict()
        row = 1

        for prop in properties:
            ## LABELS
            property_label = tk.Label(
                self.window, text=f"{prop.title()} name:", bg="#D8C7F0"
            )
            property_label.grid(row=row, column=1)
            # ENTRYS
            property_entry = tk.Entry(
                self.window,
                bg="#D8C7F0",
                width=30,
            )
            property_entry.grid(row=row, column=2)
            try:
                 property_entry.insert(0, Sample.known_properties.get(prop))
            except:
                pass

            self.properties[prop] = property_entry
            row += 1

        ## MW
        MW_label = tk.Label(
            self.window,
            text=f"Molecular weight of the protein [{MOLECULAR_WEIGHT_UNITS}]",
            bg="#D8C7F0",
        )
        MW_label.grid(row=row, column=1)

        MW_entry = tk.Entry(
            self.window,
            bg="#D8C7F0",
            width=30,
        )
        MW_entry.grid(row=row, column=2)
        row += 1
        try:
            MW_entry.insert(0, Sample.known_molecular_weights.get(self.name))
        except:
            pass

        # n_reps
        if n_reps is None:
            n_reps_label = tk.Label(
                self.window,
                text=f"Number of repetitions",
                bg="#D8C7F0",
            )
            n_reps_label.grid(row=row, column=1)
            n_reps_entry = tk.Entry(
                self.window,
                bg="#D8C7F0",
                width=30,
            )
            n_reps_entry.grid(row=row, column=2)
            try:
                n_reps_entry.insert(0, Sample.last_n_reps)
            except:
                pass
        row += 1

        # n_concentrations
        if n_concentrations is None:
            n_concentrations_label = tk.Label(
                self.window,
                text=f"Number of concentrations per repetition",
                bg="#D8C7F0",
            )
            n_concentrations_label.grid(row=row, column=1)
            n_concentrations_entry = tk.Entry(
                self.window,
                bg="#D8C7F0",
                width=30,
            )
            n_concentrations_entry.grid(row=row, column=2)
        row += 1

        # Start running
        sample_run_var = tk.StringVar()

        def sample_run():
            print("buttom pressed")
            sample_run_var.set("Run")

        button_run = tk.Button(self.window, text="Run", command=sample_run)
        button_run.grid(row=50, column=1, padx=20)

        # Exit button
        button_exit = tk.Button(
            self.window,
            text="Exit",
            command=lambda: destroy(self.window, sample_run_var),
        )
        button_exit.grid(row=50, column=2)

        # Let the window wait for any events
        print("wait")
        button_run.wait_variable(sample_run_var)
        print("waited")

I know it is difficult only with this chunk of code and my poor explanation to understand what is going on, but maybe there is something stupid that I have been missing out and more experienced people can pinpoint easily. I would love that my code don't get stuck in that wait_variable forever!

Are you using another wait_something call? If so, look into this question

It is most likely due to multiple instances of Tk().

Thank you so much! Solved :D I know it was kind of related to that but couldn't understand why in other protocols it was working when there was also several instances. Refering to the window when initializing the variable (tk.StrVar(self.window) instead of tk.StrVar()) solved the problem!
